# Embed tag not displaying

Tags: html, svg

when I write the link to my SVG file in my Embed tag, it downloads it instead of displaying it.

```
<embed src="https://gitlab.com/trtarchive/webitem/-/raw/main/agt_logo-Kopya-1.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="100%" height="100%" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0">
```

What is the reason for this? What do I need to do to view it?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <video width="100%" controls>
            <source src="data:application/x-mpegURL;base64,..." type="application/x-mpegURL">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```